# List of subscribers to a YouTube channel

Tags: youtube

Is there any way I can create an HTML list of subscribers to a channel using the YouTube APIs?

I searched for something on this site:
[API - Youtube](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/)

There is this term, but I do not know if this is the way:
`youtube.activities.list`, which returns all the events of a channel.

**EDIT**

How would I get with my channel subscribers?

Comment: `youtube.subscriptions.list` - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list

Comment: I'm trying, but I'm having difficulties.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access another Person's subscriber list. Only the channel owner can do that. You can get the subscriber amount though.